# Нахождение целых корней диофантового уравнения(генетический алгоритм)

Tags: java

Пытаюсь заполнить массив `public int[] alleles = new int[4];` класса `Gene` рандомными числами от `0` до `result`, но при обращении к этому массиву из функции `solve()` класса `Diafant`, выдаёт ошибку `NullPointerException`. Строка, где возникает исключение, помечена в коде.

Класс **Gene**:

```
public class Gene {
    public int[] alleles = new int[4];
    int fitness;
    float likelihood;

    // Test for equality.
    public boolean equalOperator(Gene gene) {
        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            if (gene.alleles[i] != alleles[i]) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Класс **Diofant**:

```
public class Diofant {
final int MAXPOPULATION = 25;
int ca, cb, cc, cd;   //coefficients
int result;
Gene[] population = new Gene[MAXPOPULATION];  //MaxPopulation

public Diofant(int a, int b, int c, int d, int res) {
    this.ca = a;
    this.cb = b;
    this.cc = c;
    this.cd = d;
    this.result = res;
}

public Gene getGene(int i) {
    return population[i];
}

int solve() {
    int fitness = -1;
    // Generate initial generation
    for(int i = 0; i < MAXPOPULATION; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            population[i].alleles[j] = (int) (Math.random() * (result + 1)); //ИСКЛЮЧЕНИЕ ЗДЕСЬ !!!!
        }
    }

    if (fitness == createFitnesses()) {
        return fitness;
    }

    int iterations = 0;   // keep track of the iterations
    while (fitness != 0 || iterations < 50) {
        generateLikelihoods();
        createNewPopulation();
        if (fitness == createFitnesses()) {
            return fitness;
        }
        iterations++;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Ну так логично. Когда ты создаешь массив объектов, они все по умолчанию имеют значение null, а ты пытаешься у этого null взять свойство alleles

Comment: @NarasuOo как сделать чтобы эти обьекты были не null?

Comment: просто создавай эти экземпляры через new в цикле и вставляй в массив